# Foundation 5 - orbit.js rotates images placed into its container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation 5 on top of a rails 4 app.

I have a page that includes an orbit.js slider.

The images are located in my app/assets/images folder and are of varying dimensions

I am using the following code to display them

```
<div class="large-6 columns">
  <ul class="home-images-container" data-orbit>
    <li>
      <%= image_tag "some_image.jpg" %>
      <div class="orbit-caption">
        Caption One.
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <%= image_tag "some_image(2).jpg" %>
      <div class="orbit-caption">
        Caption Two.
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have not altered any of the orbit.js or foundation.js code in my app

The image displays on the page but for some reason it is rotated on its side. It seems like the orbit program is trying to fit the image inside of the container however I have used it in the past and have not had this issue. Any suggestions on how to fix this behavior?

This is my first question on stack overflow so i am obviously new to this whole process so any sort of constructive criticisms on this post would also be welcomed.

Comment: what you mean by `rotated on its side` , sorry do you mean it is coming with `around corner` or it is compressed or not filling properly ?

Comment: Not sure how to describe this properly. The images are processed by the program and their oreintation is changed from their original, as in these images look like they have been rotated 90 degrees. Not sure if they are being compressed and that is causing the behavior or what.

Comment: Hey @patsul12, did you find a solution for this? I'm having a similar issue whereby the very last image is rotated 90degress. However, only on my iPhone and iPad.